# How to mix mapped 'Reference' and listed 'No Reference' hasMany relationships in one Domain Class?

Tags: grails, has-many, grails-domain-class, grails-orm

In Grails `hasMany` allows one domain class to establish a cascading *has many* relationship with another **domain class**. There are two main styles of relationships when using `hasMany`: a **mapped** property Reference and **listed** no property reference.

`hasMany` with property references:

```
class Car {
     static hasMany = [parts:Part, wheels:Wheel]
}
```

`hasMany` relationships without property references:

```
class Car {
     static hasMany = [Part, Wheel]
}
```

Here's the problem, how do I mix the two above styles?

Say I want to have a direct reference to the Wheels, but I don't want a domain property reference for the Parts.

How would I write the code for this in the Domain Class?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Car {
     Set wheels // could also use List, if you wanted indexed property
     static hasMany = [Part, Wheel]
}
```

Here's the rub though, even if you don't define it, you will end up with a `Set wheels` in your domain.  And if you look at the latest [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.1%20Association%20in%20GORM) on the Grails web site, the map version is the more common approach.